# Parse JSON in Bash

Tags: json, bash, shell, unix, curl

I'm trying to get the value of a json array but I don't manage to get the value of a leaf, can anyone help me?

Here's the json from [maps.googleapis.com/maps/api](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=59.94473,30.294254&destination=59.80612,30.308552&sensor=false&departure_time=1346197500&mode=transit)

I'd like to get the duration text and value and here's the script I've been using so far.

```
function jsonValue() {
KEY=$1
num=$2
awk -F"[,:}]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/'$KEY'\042/){print $(i+1)}}}' | tr -d '"' | sed -n ${num}p
}

curl --get --include 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=59.94473,30.294254&destination=59.80612,30.308552&sensor=false&departure_time=1346197500&mode=transit&format=json'  | jsonValue duration["value"] 2
```

Thanks in advance,
Jeremie.

Comment: You really don't want to use Bash to parse structured languages, especially if the API is not under your control. Have you tried Python, Java, or Ruby? They all have excellent support for structured data languages.

Comment: See: [How to parse JSON with shell scripting in Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121718/74329)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)
(a lightweight and flexible command-line JSON processor).

Comment: The tool seems the right one. Now, how to achieve what the OP is looking for?

Comment: Example: `wget -qO - 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=59.94473,30.294254&destination=59.80612,30.308552&sensor=false&departure_time=1346197500&mode=transit' | jq '.routes[].legs[].steps[].duration["value"]'`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
curl -G -k --data "origin=59.94473,30.294254&destination=59.80612,30.308552&sensor=false&departure_time=1346197500&mode=transit" http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json | jq '.routes[].legs[].duration["text"]'
```